# ASP.NET DatePicker (VB)

Tags: asp.net

I don't see any date picker in ASP.NET controls.

Anyone knows how to add it in my my webpage.

I am using VB as my programming language.

**Result**

I would like to thank everyone who posted the solutions, code and links which helped me to achieve this thread goal.  Based on all of the source the below code is the one which works nicely.

**Content1**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //initialise the datepicker with the date format specified
            $(".datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

And in

**Content2**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_MyDate" CssClass="datepicker" MaxLength="10" />
```

Comment: Is this a question asked by a user with close to 1k votes???!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Could you please share the link?  Also it should be VB since I don't know C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this inside your [head] Tag.

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and use this jquery function in aspx page inside [script] tag

```
    $(function () {

    $("#datepicker").datepicker();

    $("#datepicker").change(function () {
        $('#btnRefresh').click();

    });
```

and add one textbox for display selected date. and button for getting the date in sever side. like this code

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />


    <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" onclick="btnRefresh_Click" ClientIDMode="Static"
        Text="Refresh" AutoPostback="true" style="display:none;"/>
```

use this onclick event to do want you want..

Comment: Getting compile error in btnRefresh_Click' is not a member of ASP.menu_pages

Comment: have you create a event in sever side?

Comment: No I have not done it since I don't know how to do it :(  Since the codes are confusing me since C# and Java codes are not like VB.Net

Comment: protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          
      }

Comment: like this. add this method in your sever side

Comment: Thank you for your continuous support and now the date picker is working fine and I also updated the working code in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there isn't anything built-in.
Personally I would recommend the jQueryUI datepicker - it's reliable and flexible, and it's javascript based, so it doesn't matter what your server-side language is.

See https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Once you've added the required references to jQuery and jQueryUI, in your aspx page, add a script section like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        //initialise the datepicker with the date format specified
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

and then add the "datepicker" class to any textbox controls on the page where you want to use the datepicker:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_MyDate" CssClass="datepicker" MaxLength="10" />
```

P.S. I can also recommend most of the rest of the jQueryUI package, there are some useful items in there which can speed up your development time and make your apps look nicer and be more usable.

Comment: It looks good.  But I don't know where I have to paste those codes.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Sixthsense the first one can go anywhere on your aspx page. The second one is the markup that is used to generate a textbox (again this is in your aspx page). The bit that tells it to use the datepicker is the `CssClass="datepicker"` part. If you're using the visual designer currently, you just need to switch to the source view to see this. I get the sense you are quite new to ASP.NET development, so it may be worth doing some more general reading/training before you go much further.

Comment: Yes exactly I am a newbie to asp.net.  Whatever you are referring above is completely out of my areas of expertization.  So don't know where to begin...

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a datepicker on your page with the help of the Calendar control, using javascript on your page. Try this links for simple methods to do it:

http://www.vbknowledgebase.com/?Id=150&Desc=ASP.Net-DatePicker-using-Calendar-Control

http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/247_DatePicker_Control_in_ASPNet.aspx

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/DateTimePicker-control-for-ASPNet-TextBox-Example.aspx